# Wordpress - Get posts with specific ACF value

Tags: wordpress, foreach, advanced-custom-fields

I have a website that's making use of the FacetWP plugin and Advanced Custom Fields for making extra fields for the posts.

Each post can have a "Department" value and I need to make a foreach for the different departments like this:

```
if ($department == "Office") {
    get all the post with the Value Office from the ACF field "department."
}
```

The custom field is a select/dropdown field.

I also need to do this same thing for other departments like "Production", "Boss", "Drinks". But I need to give the departments a title with the results below it.

What is the best way to do this?

Regards,

Update:

What I need to have in the end is this on one page in an overview:

Title: Office
 - Employee 1
 - Employee 2
 - Employee 3
 - Employee 4

Title: Production
 - Employee 1
 - Employee 2
 - Employee 3

Title: Boss
 - Employee 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The custom field ‘ location’ in this case could be a text field, radio button or select field (something that saves a single text value).

```
<?php 

 $location = get_field('location');

// args
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'event',
    'meta_key'      => 'location',
    'meta_value'    => $location
);


// query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>
<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
     <h1> <?php echo $location ?> </h1>
    <ul>
    <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <img src="<?php the_field('event_thumbnail'); ?>" />
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>
```

Comment: I forgot to tell, the custom field is a select/dropdown field

Comment: as I mentioned in the text of my answer, this is valid for dropdown as well but ti should not be multi-value select. Means you are selection one value only. it that okay?

Comment: Yes, only one value is possible, thanks! I will try to use this code.

Comment: If this helped. please accept and upvote the answer.

Comment: Yes, for one specific department it's working. But I need it to use for more departments, I've updated my answer with the exact thing I need.

Comment: @n00bly The Title thing can be done very easily. use a variable to store the acf value and use that for the title and meta_value both. Updated the Answer

Comment: I tried the new code, but i'n only getting 10 results instead of 216. And the $location does not show any value, I think because it's outside the while?

Comment: echo the $location and fix if that value is coming from acf or not. There is no impact of while on $location because it's a value from acf using get_field. Also,I updated the post_per_page in args.

Comment: Thanks, the post per page is fixed. But how can the act field "$location" know from which post it should get the location. The website is a internal page with all the employees that work there. I want to show all the employees in the different departments. So I get department title with the employees below that belong in that department. I need that for every department :)

Comment: @n00bly I can't give the complete solution. I gave you the full idea to implement, you need to take it further. I can't help coz I don't know the full code or scenario. The issue you posted has been solved via my answer.